# "Словно по волшебству"

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли сочетание "словно по волшебству" устойчивым? 
Надо ли ставить запятую, например, в таком предложении "Все вокруг замерли словно по волшебству"?

Answer (score 1):

Не могу точно сказать, надо ли считать "словно по волшебству" устойчивым сочетанием, но это в вашем примере, видимо, не является определяющим. "Словно по волшебству" здесь имеет наречное значение и тесено связано со сказуемым. Хотя в подобных случаях всегда есть повод для "авторской" пунктуации.

Comment: Хорошо, здесь — сказуемое.
Но все-таки: является ли это сочетание устойчивым? Я считаю, является. Подтверждения только не могу найти.