# Как по волшебству. Запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> ... он возникал прямо перед носом, как
> по волшебству.
> ... он, как по волшебству, возникал прямо перед носом.

Было что-то подобное [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83), но никто не пришёл ни к какому выводу. Обособляется?

Comment: @anaka2005, [здесь](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/37032/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)уже обсуждалось обособление сравнительных оборотов, и довольно подробно. Прочитайте. Думаю, все вам станет ясно.

Comment: @Серж, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборот желательно обособить  в обоих случаях.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Оборот со значением уподобления обособляется  в удобной  позиции, если предложение достаточно распространено и оборот можно отнести на второй план.

Обособленные обороты встречаются чаще, вариант с необособленным оборотом используется в нераспространенных предложениях, так как он входит в структуру основного сообщения.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Обособление

Словно по волшебству, беззвучно отворились загородки конюшни. Вдруг ворота, словно по волшебству, распахнулись. Она  преобразилась, словно по волшебству, в совсем молодую девушку.  И сразу же, как по волшебству, радиола заиграла вальс.

2) Нет обособления

Попав в нормальную правовую среду в любой европейской стране, он как по волшебству становится законопослушным человеком. И возня затихла как по волшебству. Наступает утро, и все меняется как по волшебству. Как по волшебству боль начала утихать.

3)  Не обособляется в составе другого обособленного оборота:

Пассажиры вынуждены подчиниться, а наутро, в сопровождении словно по волшебству появившихся десяти тысяч национальных гвардейцев, их отправляют под барабанный бой назад в Париж.